# WPF application connecting to Online DB?

Tags: mysql, wpf, database, connection-string

I've created a management system using WPF C# in VS2012.
I'm currently using SQLEXPRESS as my local database, using CRUD commands as simple as i can and know.
I wanted to know how can i connect my app to an online database using this details.
I've tried connecting this app to 000webhost changing my connectionString in App.config ,as I understood searching the web, that it can't be done directly, their interface is very easy a thing i liked most.
I'm a newbie to everything surrounding hosting sites, remote Databases, publishing in VS.
A walkthrough would be an ideal solution, Thanks in advance.

Edit: I tried using byethost hosting MySQL service.
While this is my connectionString:

```
  string connString = "server=sql305.byethost3.com;database=b3_14716837_main;uid=b3_14716837;pwd=Mp949u24";
```

This is my info from the provider.

I'm getting an error "Unable to connect to any specific MySQL Hosts", what seems to be the problem ? is it the hosting provider ?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem and I can't figure out a solution, But I heard something called Remote Access to the Mysql database enable to access from different location.

So I create a PHP Web Service in my server and I call this PHP file and get data throught the JSON it's easy.